# Did Taki and Mitsuha appear in "Weathering With You"?

Tags: your-name, weathering-with-you

Many people say that Taki and Mitsuha from *Your Name* also appeared in *Weathering With You*.

Did they really appear? If so, when did they appear?

Comment: https://www.thebobaculture.com/anime/do-taki-and-mitsuha-from-your-name-appear-in-weathering-with-you

Answer (score 4):

As it's said in [this answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/57983/69917) they do appear.

Taki appears in his grandmother's house around minute 44.

[image]

Mitsuha appears around minute 51 as a saleswoman when Hodaka is buying a ring for Hina.

[image]

Comment: What does this answer add to already existing answer? You are just referencing the other answer.

Comment: @FumikageTokoyami It adds screenshots, timestamps, and a more precise description of the scene where Mitsuha appears. Maybe you feel all this is not enough to warrant another answer, but it's still not nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the characters do appear in it, but not as main characters. Taki and Mitsuha are supporting characters in *Weathering With You*.

Taki shows up in the house of the last sunshine girl place. As for Mitsuha, I don't remember, but I see that it is stated on [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/) that she does appear.

This can be verified with a quick [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/) search for *[Kimi no Na wa](https://myanimelist.net/anime/32281/Kimi_no_Na_wa?q=kimi%20no%20na%20)* and *[Tenki no Ko](https://myanimelist.net/anime/38826/Tenki_no_Ko?q=tenki%20no%20ko)*.